# Paragon as a Verb

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, verbs

In my vocabulary studies, I seem to constantly catch a snag on the word paragon. The noun is completely second nature to me, but I cannot seem to grasp the usage and definition of its verb counterpart. According to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/paragon):

> verb. to compare; parallel.

My confusion stems from my inability to track down any usage of it as a verb, almost all examples are using the noun form, reading the phrase *paragon of xyz* over and over to the point of drivel.

If someone could direct me to examples or explain it to me differently, I'll thoroughly appreciate it.

Comment: Paragon as a verb is rare or archaic: verb (used with object)
5.
Rare. to compare; parallel.
6.
Archaic. to be a match for; rival.
7.
Obsolete. to surpass.
8.
Obsolete. to regard as a paragon.

Comment: @Josh Yeah, that's what I linked in the original post. Exactly why I want to find out more about it. Studying vocabulary, remember? :)

Comment: So what is your question? Just looking for an example usage?

Comment: @Josh "If someone could direct me to examples or explain it to me differently, I'll thoroughly appreciate it." Not sure if you actually read the post.

Comment: ***paragon (n.):*** - 
1540s, from Middle French paragon "a model, pattern of excellence" (15c., Modern French parangon), ***from Italian paragone, originally "touchstone to test gold" (early 14c.), from paragonare "to test on a touchstone, compare,"***

Comment: Paragonare is a common Italian verb, it didn't survive in French and in English as a verb, though.

Comment: ***To paragon***:  *To serve as a model for; to surpass.*
(Shakespeare)
*He hath achieved a maid / That paragons description and wild fame.*

Comment: ***To paragon*** - To compare with; to equal; to rival.

(Glover)
*In arms anon to paragon the morn, / The morn new rising.*

Comment: to 'catch a snag on…' anything would be meaningless in any dialect of modern English.

Could you put the basic premise at leat one other way, please

Comment: Wonder Woman paragons Superman as ideals of their respective genders.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for examples, with no indication of what would constitute a "best" or "most useful" example in keeping with the StackExchange model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand why *to paragon* means *to compare*, you can look at the Italian version of the word (*paragone* for the noun, *paragonare* for the verb).

The Italian *Vocabolario Treccani* [says this](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/paragonare/) about the verb:

> **paragonare** v. tr. [dal gr. παρακονάω «sfregare contro, affilare», (...) Saggiare l’oro, sulla pietra di paragone o con altro metodo

Translation:

> **to paragon** v. tr. [from Greek παρακονάω «rub against, sharpen», (...) Assaying gold, on the touchstone [lit. "paragon stone"] or using another method

Basically, the Italian *pietra di paragone* is a touchstone. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchstone_(assaying_tool)):

> Drawing a line with gold on a touchstone will leave a visible trace. Because different alloys of gold have different colours (see gold) **the unknown sample can be compared** to samples of known purity.

Therefore, many years ago people used *to paragon* alleged gold with actual gold, using a touchstone. The actual gold itself became known as *a paragon* i.e. a reference model, which is now the first definition from [the dictionary you cited](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/paragon):

> a model or pattern of excellence or of a particular excellence